# move all layers on a canvas in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, layers, gif

I have a huge gif file that I am editing in photoshop. I am newish to photoshop and have not been able to find any way to move all of the layers within the canvas without toggling the visibility, switching to, and moving each layer individually which is a massive pain. How would a power-user go about solving this problem?

Comment: how would I know if the layer was locked?

Comment: It will have a lock icon to the right

Comment: [Layers 101](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/atv/cs6-tutorials/layers-101.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Click on the top layer in your layers palette
- Scroll to the bottom one, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>, click on it.

This should select all layers. No need to unhide hidden layers, because they will move either way, as long as they are not locked.

Beware of layer masks. If they aren't locked to their corresponding layer or group, the mask will remain in place, while the art it's meant to be masking will move.